# Javascript replacing single quote with empty string

Tags: javascript

This is an odd one! I kind of want to say the reason my `replace` function isn't working correctly is because of the font. I've never seen this issue before, and I wonder if I'm overlooking something!?

I have the following variable set to a static text with `'`.

```
var lastName = "O'Donnell";
```

In my browser, `console.log(lastName)` outputs: `O’Donnell`. Instead of `O'Donnell`. Therefore, the following replace method isn't working.

Screenshot:
[image]

```js
return lastName.replace(/'/g, '')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not a `'` character, it's actually a ["smart quote"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_marks_in_English#Typing_quotation_marks_on_a_computer_keyboard) character.  It's unicode point is `U+2019`.  You can try to use the regex `/\u2019/g`.

Comment: console.log(lastName) outputs: O'Donnell as intended on chrome for me. Maybe try a different browser ?

Comment: @user2202098: The screenshot shows that it's not a `'` character.  He must the smart quote in his code  (if you copy and paste from MS word, it sometimes does this).  Also, those characters don't always stay when copying and pasting into other programs or as plain text.

Comment: I didn't. I specifically used `'`. My local dev site displays a different text than the client's dev site. Even though, the source code is the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The character you're trying to replace isn't the same as the one in the name.

Best to remove all non alpha numeric characters instead, to cater for names such as:

- O'Neill
- St. Mary's

Try:

```
lastName.replace(/\W/g, '')
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much.